# JUnit tests fail when running them with Ant

Tags: java, ant, junit, classpath

I know this is a duplicate. I've read numerous posts on the same issue yet I still can't make this work for me.

I am trying to figure out how to run JUnit tests with Ant. I created a simple new project with NetBeans:
[image]

This is how it looks on the filesystem ('lib' folder contains `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` and `junit-4.12.jar`):
[image]

And this is the build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="main" basedir=".">

    <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
    <property name="test.dir" location="test" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />
    <property name="classes.src.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes_src" />
    <property name="classes.test.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes_test" />

    <target name="main" depends="junit">
        <echo message="targets complete" />
    </target>

    <target name="junit" depends="compile">
        <junit>
            <classpath>
                <path>
                    <pathelement path="${classes.test.dir}" />
                    <pathelement path="${classes.src.dir}" />
                    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                </path>
            </classpath>
            <test name="myproject.CalcTest" />
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="makedir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.src.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${classes.test.dir}">
            <classpath>
                <path>
                    <pathelement location="${classes.src.dir}" />
                    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*.jar" />
                    </fileset>
                </path>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="makedir" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.src.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.test.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

</project>
```

If I run this i get `[junit] Test myproject.CalcTest FAILED`. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What´s the cause for the failure? There must be a more detailed message.

Comment: How can i check this? I am pretty sure it is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalcTEST based on other similar posts. Also junitreport tells me that no tests are actually executed.

Comment: run ant with `-verbose`to see more output.

Comment: I got this: `[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec`. Unfortunately no specifics on the error.

Comment: I didn't see the failure, but maybe you can use the Ant template from https://github.com/mplacona/java-junit-template-project/blob/master/build.xml

Comment: Add as a child of `<junit>`: `<formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>`. This will give details about the failed test.

Comment: What's the name of your ant build file where you are executing test tasks?